# Finding duplicates (one row/ea) and listing number of duplicates per lookup code

Tags: sql, duplicates

I'm trying to query for products with duplicates, but with only one row per duplicate entry. I also want each entry to show how many others like it there are. Here's what I have so far, but it's got a lot of errors. Tips on how to streamline and troubleshoot would be appreciated.

```
 SELECT p1.id AS product_id,
 p1.lookup_code AS product_lookup_code,
 p1.name AS product_name,
 p2.id AS duplicate_id,
 p2.lookup_code AS duplicate_lookup_code,
 p2.name AS duplicate_name,
 COUNT(*) (FROM products AS p1 INNER JOIN products AS p2 ON p1.lookup_code = p2.lookup_code 
 INNER JOIN items ON p1.id = items.product_id 
 WHERE p1.id != p2.id 
 AND items.available = true 
 AND items.visible = true 
 AND items.unlisted = false) 
 HAVING COUNT > 1 LIMIT 5000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.id, p.lookup_code, p.name, t.duplicate_count from products p INNER JOIN (
  SELECT count(id) as duplicate_count, lookup_code from products GROUP BY lookup_code HAVING count(id) > 1
) t on t.lookup_code = products.lookup_code;
```